# how to create a table with a supervisor referencing another supervisor

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a table explaining how one representative reports to another but dont know quite how?

[image: I need to create a table explaining how one representative reports to another but dont know quite how?]

```
Create table Representative (RID int , TOID int, Rname varchar(10), Rphone varchar(15), PRIMARY KEY (RID), FOREIGN KEY (TOID) REFERENCES TourOperator);
```

The code above is my attempt but dont know how to introduce the reports to

do I create another variable called super_ID? and add it to table or how can i relate one representative to another in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd add another column (`SUPER_ID`) into the table  which will be a foreign key, pointing to `RID`.

Comment: would it be like this Create table Representative (RID int , TOID int, Rname varchar(10), Rphone varchar(15), SuperID int, PRIMARY KEY (RID), FOREIGN KEY (TOID) REFERENCES TourOperator, FOREIGN KEY (SuperID) REFERENCES Representative);

Comment: the table goes through but i want to make sure its doing the proper function

Comment: It is, at least the way you described it.